# Natural examples of removable discontinuities?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, examples-counterexamples, continuity

Are there any natural examples of removable discontinuities? Most examples I've seen start with a continuous function, and then change the value of a random point, which isn't very natural.

Note that I am *not* counting examples where the function doesn't exist at the discontinuity ($\frac{\sin x}x$ at 0, for example). I want looking for a natural example of a function $f$ such that for some $c$: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) = L$$ $$f(c)=V$$ $$V \neq L$$

EDIT: This is naturally a [soft-question](/questions/tagged/soft-question), and so somewhat subjective, but I would consider a function "natural" if it isn't defined specifically as an example of a function with a removable discontinuity. The removable discontinuity should be a byproduct, not the goal, of the functions definition.

Comment: You might want to more adequately define "*natural example of a function.*"  The examples you have already seen are probably already what I would call natural examples.  Most could be rephrased in terms of using dirac delta functions, indicator functions, heavyside functions, or similar in order to artificially induce the removable discontinuity if what bothers you so much about the normal examples is that they are piecewise defined.

Comment: @JMoravitz I attempted to address this in an edit. I'm not sure how precisely I can define it, so maybe this isn't a good question on this site. If it gets closed, and ask on reddit or something.

Comment: An example of a function which might satisfy you, the function $\text{IsInteger}(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if}~x\in\Bbb Z\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ can be written instead as $\text{IsInteger}(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor -x\rfloor + 1$.  This has removable discontinuities at every integer.

Comment: @JMoravitz That would work, although I would like functions with a little more structure a little bit better.

Comment: Another fun example, $\text{sgn}(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if}~x>0\\0&\text{if}~x=0\\-1&\text{if}~x<0\end{cases}=\lfloor\frac{x}{|x|+1}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{-x}{|-x|+1}\rfloor$.  Using this we can then define $\text{IsZero}(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if}~x=0\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ as $1-|\text{sgn}(x)|$.  We can then further define $\text{Is}_c(x)=\begin{cases}c&\text{if}~x=c\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ as $\text{IsZero}(x-c)$.  We can then add multiples of $\text{Is}_c(x)$ to any continuous function you want to induce the specific discontinuities.

Comment: So for example $f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2+2&\text{if}~x\neq 2\\8&\text{if}~x=2\end{cases}$ can be written as $f(x)=x^2+2+2\text{Is}_2(x)$ where we can backtrack and replace $\text{Is}_2(x)$ with an expression involving absolute value signs and floor functions.

Comment: [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) has a removable discontinuity at every rational point, but I don't know how "natural" it is.

Comment: I saw "V$\not=$L" and momentarily thought of something [very different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_constructibility).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is natural for you or not, but here it goes:$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1+nx^2}.\end{array}$$It is clear that $f(0)=1$ and also that $x\neq0\implies f(x)=0$.